# Function that returns a reference?

Tags: c++, class

I am wondering, why are functions that return a reference value useful? It doesn't make much sense to me, since functions are not lvalues anyway...

Here is an example of a function... well not a function it's an assignment operator overload in a class but it looks like this

```
//class name is MyClass
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& source){
//do things(assign values from the source to the current object)
return *this;
}
```

Why would you want that class to return a reference? :/ (I found this similar code in a video tutorial here is the link if needed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXcRe-W2w7s )

Comment: "since functions are not lvalues anyway" - not sure what you mean by that. It's not the function being referenced, it's the return object.

Comment: You can ignore that part, not so important

Comment: not so important? really

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vector<int> v(5);
v.at(0) = 666;
```

This works only because `at` returns a reference.

Comment: @Schrustra Because if it returned by value, you would be assigning to the temporary value that is returned, not the element of the vector. We expect this to assign to the element of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

If the reference is returned, the caller can use it for chaining of calls. In your example, it reflects the convention that an assigment is also a value (or an object), namely the value (or object) which is assigned.

Comment: I would phrase that as "the result of an assignment is an object, namely the object which is being assigned to." The distinction between object and value here is important.

Comment: that's not true, can use chaining even if you don't return a reference.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg agree, but I think Codor should clarify this, as it is commonly believed that "chaining" doesn't even compile if `operator=` doesn't return a reference. Things like `a=b=c` will always work, but `(a=b) = c` will compile but won't do what one expects when `operator=` returns by value.

Comment: @vsoftco How is chaning possible if no referenc is returned?

Comment: @Codor Can you explain why it's impossible if a reference is not returned?

Comment: @Schrustra, `(a=b)=c` will compile, however `(a=b)` returns by value some temporary `X`, then that temporary `X` invokes `operator=(c)`. At the end, `a` will be equal to `b`, but not `c`.

Comment: No, this is a misunderstanding. Chaining of assignments is also possible if the return type is `MyClass` instead of `MyClass&`.

Comment: @Codor, maybe I wasn't clear, what I meant is that the code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/075a8d2a81edb941 gives different results depending wether `operator=` returns by value or by reference. In particular, `(a=b) = c` has `a==c` at the end of the day only if `operator=` returns by reference.

Comment: Ah ok. It is subtle! I find this question a bit confusing. Although I understand the accepted answer, I don't really see how it relates to the original question. `at` is not a member of the object whose reference is returned.

Comment: I think in assignment operator you return by reference to avoid issues I mentioned before, and also to avoid un-necessary copies (although most compilers can optimize via return value optimization). As for other functions, the accepted answer gave the reason.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to `C++` the result of the assignment operator in `C` is `rvalue` instead of `lvalue` :)

So in C++ you may write

```
int a, b = 1, c = 2;

( a = b ) = c;
```

and `a` will get the value of `c` discarding the previously assigned value of `b`.

In C such a code will not be compiled.

As for you question about references then such functions are very useful. Consider for example member functions of class `std::basic_string`.

You may write for example

```
std::string s( "Hello" );

std::cout << ( s.append( 1, ' ' ) += "World" ) << std::endl;
```

It is possible because both member functions `append` and operator `+=` return reference to the original pbject.